# Do the concentration of electrons in a circuit affect the magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrons

Beware that I am going to make a few statements and not all if any of them are necessarily true or possible. I do not know whether my premises or my main question makes sense.

Assume that an AC-coil of 5V @ 50Mhz has a significantly higher concentration of electrons in it compared to another AC-coil of 5V @ 50 Mhz.

Assume that the current in them are identical all the time. 1A measured somehow.

A high concentration of electrons move slower than a lower concentration if both concentrations move with 1A.

Would this difference in electron concentration affect the induced magnetic field in any way? If electrons were to oscillate in an antenna then they would in this scenario oscillate although at the same frequencies but different distances. Does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

For not too small currents it does not make a difference. All that matters for the fields is the charge and the current. At low current intensities it *does* matter. Then shot noise will appear due to the fact that the current is caused by a finite number of discrete charge carriers. In the limit of a small mumber of carriers it may become necessary to consider them individually and use a quantum mechanical approach.

Comment: If all that matters (usually) for the field is the charge and the current, then wouldn't two circuits yield different magnetic fields if both are 1V,1A,5Mhz if the circuits are charged differently or if for some reason the electrons move slower (but denser) in one of them?